# Evaluate $\int x^2 \sin(7x^3)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Evaluate $$\int x^2 \sin(7x^3)dx.$$

Can somebody check my solution? Thanks!

Let $u = 7x^3$, then $du = 21x^2dx$ and so $\dfrac{du}{21x^2}=dx$.

Thus we have: $$\int x^2 \sin(7x^3)dx=\frac{1}{21} \int \sin(u)du = \frac{-1}{21}\cos(u)+C = \frac{-1}{21}\cos(7x^3)+C$$

Comment: You can instantly check things like this on Wolfram Alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+sin%287x%5E3%29

Comment: I recommend using this site: https://www.integral-calculator.com/ (It is free of charge in case Wolfram Alpha tells you to pay them in order to view the way)

Comment: i like posting them here for mah students tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is perfect! It could not be done better.

Although, you could check it by your self by taking the derivative of your result.